# HTML-store checked items in a array

Tags: html, arrays

How to store the items checked in a checkbox in an array?
I tried using a for loop but it didn't work

```
for(i=0;i<selectedQuote.length;i++) {

}
```

Comment: Can we see the code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will serve your purpose.

```js
function ShowValue(){
  var arrayTemp=[];
  $('input[type=\"checkbox\"]:checked').each(function(){
    arrayTemp.push($(this).val());
  });
  /*
    If you want to itterate the array
    for(var i=0;i<arrayTemp.length;i++){
      console.log(arrayTemp[i]);
    }
  */
  $("#result").html(arrayTemp);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="val1">Val 1
    <input type="checkbox" value="val2">Val 2
    <input type="checkbox" value="val3">Val 3
    <button onclick="return ShowValue()"> Show </button>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option using querySelectorAll to get all checkboxes using attribute name

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('[name=sports]');//all checkbox elements
var checkbox =[];

for(var i =0; i < elem.length; i++){
  if(elem[i].checked){
    checkbox.push(elem[i].value)
  }
}
console.log(checkbox)
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OQoBeL

For capturing the checked elements dynamically use addEventListener

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('[name=sports]');//all checkbox elements
var checkbox =[];

for(var i =0; i < elem.length; i++){
    elem[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.checked)
    if(e.target.checked){
      checkbox.push(e.target.value)
      console.log(checkbox)
    }else{
      checkbox.splice(checkbox.indexOf(e.target.value),1)
      console.log(checkbox)
    }

});

}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rJZQOp